# org.apache.http.client-4.3.6: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: java, android, apache, dependencies, unirest

I am working in Android. I am trying to install dependencies (without maven) for the [Unirest library](http://unirest.io/java). I have added the exact versions of the dependencies, namely:  httpclient 4.3.6, httpmime 4.3.6, httpasyncclient 4.0.2.

However, i am still getting this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.abdulwasae.odnvt_1, PID: 12678
                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
                                                   at com.mashape.unirest.http.options.Options.refresh(Options.java:72)
                                                   at com.mashape.unirest.http.options.Options.<clinit>(Options.java:46)
                                                   at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.prepareRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:151)
                                                   at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:131)
                                                   at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
                                                   at com.abdulwasae.odnvt_1.ODFragment$2.onClick(ODFragment.java:225)
                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

According to the relevant [Apache Javadocs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html), this definition was present in the org.apache.httpclient in the version as early as 4.3.

I am stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, here is my gradle snapshot in case it helps:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abdulwasae.odnvt_1"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' // will not include DEPENDENCIES file
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile files('libs/unirest-java-1.4.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpasyncclient-4.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
}
```

**UPDATE**
I checked to confirm if the troubling class could be found in any one of the added dependencies. And, yes, it does show in httpclient-4.3.6.jar

[image: class in httpclient-4.3.6.jar]

I wonder what to check next.

Comment: why do you use HttpClient, it 's deprecated, Use HttpUrlConnection.

Comment: Because it's a dependency requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [unirest-java-1.4.9-SNAPSHOT-withDependency-ShadedForAndroid](http://www.mediafire.com/download/vreluxa6t1itwnb/unirest-java-1.4.9-SNAPSHOT-withDependency-ShadedForAndroid.jar). It can be built by following [this](http://blog.mashape.com/installing-unirest-java-with-the-maven-assembly-plugin/) tutorial.

Comment: does  the job for me! ;) However, the issue above remains a mystery

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError always means you are missing a jar file.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Looks like its in httpcomponent-client, try adding:

```
 compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-client:4.5.2'
```

to your build file.

Comment: Are you sure though? Arent 'noClassFound' and 'noClassDefFound'  different?

Comment: Use Jarzilla or Zip to open then jar file and look for the class referenced. org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager If its there then its a classpath problem. If its missing, then keep looking in httpcomponents core of one of the related libs.

Comment: Also, I see you're using httpclient, which is a different lib than httpcomponents.

Comment: Http components is just a set of many jars including HttpClient. Are you suggesting that i add all of the jars in this set and try?

Comment: Ok i will try the jarzilla methid and get back

Comment: Bottom line is that the classloader cannot find the referenced class. It either means you've got the wrong library or its not on your classpath at runtime.

Comment: Thank you. I'll perform on your suggestions and insights and then come back

Comment: Hello @Griff
Could you have a look at the image i have posted as an update to my question?